# Vantagens x Desvantagens SPA VueJs

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application

Possuo uma aplicação(sistema fechado) em PHP estruturado na empresa que trabalho e iremos reescrever essa aplicação para melhorar performance, usabilidade e evoluir essa aplicação.

Estou estudando o VueJs e tenho gostado bastante da abordagem para utilizá-lo no FrontEnd, gostaria de saber duas coisas:

1) Supondo que faça uma SPA, o cliente entra na aplicação e passa o dia todo nela, navegando, criando dados, gerando relatórios, etc ... vou colocando uma porção de coisas no store(Vuex), isso vai deixando a aplicação/browser/navegação lenta? Em um longo tempo de uso posso ter quedas de performance?

2) Estou procurando a maneira certa de organizar os arquivos, componentes, chamadas ajax e toda essa estrutura front mas não encontrei nada muito esclarecedor até agora, alguém teria um bom material para indicar? De preferência mostrando o caminho das pedras para uma boa aplicação SPA.

Obrigado

Comment: Coloquei como resposta para ficar mais organizado.

Answer (score 1):

Em relação ao store do `vuex` creio que não afetará tanto, é tudo questão de memória e como você usa ela, é claro que em múltiplas mutações ao mesmo tempo há motivos para se preocupar, poderá obter referência nessa questão [Multiplas mutações dentro de um loop](https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/5038/slow-vuex-performance-multiple-mutations-within-a-loop)...

Na organização também é outro ponto que o `vue` deixa a sua escolha, qualquer iniciação cli `(browserify/webpack)` irá te dar essa liberdade, quer aplicar `mvc`, `ddd`, ok, o importante é a coesão. Caso necessite de uma estrutura guiada para cada componente e chamadas recomendo fortemente `ember.js`